# Trying to identify and replicate Drywall Texture

Tags: drywall, texture

What is this drywall texture called and how can I replicate it?

[image: Wall Texture]

Comment: That very distinctive line between the top 1/2 and bottom 1/2 of the picture make it look like someone already did a patch here. They did a reasonably good job of duplicating the pattern, but it just feels like there is a hard line between the two spots. I had to click to ensure that it wasn't two pics back-to-back.

Answer (score 4):

That's most likely a stiff brush applied to the wet compound.  Go to the dollar store and get a cheap plastic whisk broom.  Practice your strokes on a piece of scrap with a scratch coat applied.

Comment: Thanks Chris I appreciate the help. Will give it a try and see how well I do.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this texture before and you can use several options n swirl it into the walls..putty knife..can use a sponge, a rag but l find putty knife is smoother. Once you apply it you use the swirling motion..let it dry n prime and paint..love this texture!

Comment: Thanks Sam, I will give this a try as well.